# How to get in the CSS of the Facebook Like Button

Tags: javascript, css, facebook-like

I would like to add some CSS to the like button and the box count. How can I do it?

Comment: To those that voted to close as OT, care to explain? I'm new to facebook.stackoverflow.com but a stackoverflow.com veteran so I'm trying to figure out what the criteria for closing are here...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook, how to change like button image?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4920945/facebook-how-to-change-like-button-image)

Answer (score 7):

You can't. Facebook uses an iframe for that very reason - to prevent you from changing its appearance and function.

Comment: They have a non-iframe version too.

Comment: No, they don't. The XFBML version uses JavaScript to render an iframe. Use Firebug or another debug tool to see.